# csv file with one Dictionary column

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have one CSV file with multiple columns, one of the columns have dictionary elements, how to expand this dictionary keys to columns

Data Frame
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR4Wi.png)

Tried applying pd.Series

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpeSG.png)

output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6S1R.png)

Still it's not getting split into columns.

referred this stackoverflow solution:
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3], 'col1':[{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':3, 'b':4, 'c':5}, {'a':None, 'b':5, 'c':6}]})
df.set_index('id').col1.apply(pd.Series)
working for this data frame, but not working for my original one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using json normalise:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['address'])
```

Comment: it's not working, it's giving error : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'